# how to generate this type of tree using C++

Tags: c++, treeview

I want to generate this type of treeview using c++:

These are the input elements:

```
ID  Name        Parent
10  Item1        -1
20  Item2        -1
30  Item3        -1
40  Item1.1      10
50  Item1.2      10
60  Item1.3      10
70  Item2.1      20
80  Item3.1      20
90  Item1.2.1    30
100 Item1.2.2    50
110 Item2.1.1    70
120 Item1.2.1.1  90
```

And I want to form the following treeview:

```
=>Item1
       Item1.1

=>Item1.2
   => Item 1.2.1
           Item 1.2.2
```

Comment: What have you tried ? Let us know the issue u r facing

Comment: I don't understand how to solve this.